# How to configure Logitech Performance MX 950?

Tags: unity, mouse, logitech, button

I am completely new to Ubuntu 13.04 and I do not have much experience using terminal. However, I would like to assign the "zoom" button on my Performance MX mouse to show workspaces... I find the particular button worthless for actually zooming in and out.
I also want to assign the "application button" to "spread windows" (at least what it is called in the unity tweak tool).

How do I go about changing these settings permanently?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably figured this out by now, but for reference here is how to get the functionality you mentioned. The Logitech Performance MX 950 is also called just the Performance MX in some markets, so these instructions work for both the "Performance MX 950" and "Performance MX" models.

### Setting up Zoom and Window switcher buttons

1. Install the CompizConfig Settings Manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open the settings manager, either through the Unity menu or by typing `ccsm` in a terminal.
3. Go to the "Scale" plugin. Under the tab "Bindings", assign Button 10 to "Initiate Window Picker For All Windows" by clicking on the button in the row with the mouse icon. This will give you the spread windows functionality, using all windows from all workspaces. If you prefer to just see the windows from the current workspace, instead assign the "Initiate Window Picker" shortcut.
4. Go back, and open the settings for the "Expo" plugin. Assign Button 13 to the "Expo Button" setting. This will give you the show workspaces functionality.

All the other buttons should work out of the box in Ubuntu, at least they do for me with Ubuntu 14.04. Do not be tempted to change any other settings in `ccsm`, as you can easily break your system with it.

Additional tip: You can run `xev` in a terminal to see exactly which buttons are currently pressed.

### Setting up Solaar for additional settings, and managing the Unifying receiver

To manage the Unifying receiver and change a few settings on the Performance MX (scroll sensitivity, DPI settings), you'll need to install [Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/):

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:daniel.pavel/solaar
   ```
2. Update your sources:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install solaar:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install solaar
   ```
4. Run Solaar from the Unity menu. To make it work for the first time, you'll need to unplug the receiver, plug it back in, and turn the mouse off/on.
5. Solaar will run in the background and show a small indicator in the top menu bar (next to the Wifi indicator). You can configure your devices or quit Solaar from there.
6. Solaar will add itself to the Startup Applications, which will make it start automatically on login. Personally I find the battery notifications distracting so I have disabled the Solaar entry (just remove it from the Startup Applications).

Comment: This worked extremely well, thank you! Just a small side note though; for the "Scale" option, with your suggested settings and no other changes, you have to press and hold the button, and you move the mouse to the window you want and let go. If you don't want this behavior, make sure to check the box in the Bindings section (near the top) that says "Button Bindings Toggle Scale Mode". That way, you just press the button once and it scales.